# Magento 2.2.2 - Admin Configuration loading problem

Tags: magento2.2

I am having serious problem with CONFIGURATION - Saving and changing. I am not able to load the configuration page at all. I get this below given error, can anyone help me here.

**Magento Details:**

```
Apache Version - 2.4.29
PHP Version - 5.6.33
MySQL Version - 5.6.38
Magento Version - 2.2.2
```

> {"0":"Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php
>   on line 63","1":"#0
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined
>   index...', '/home/efabrics/...', 63, Array)\n#1
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php(146):
>   Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator->setElements(Array,
>   'default')\n#2
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getTabs()\n#3
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php(209):
>   Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getTabs()\n#4
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php(76):
>   Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getFirstSection()\n#5
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/AbstractConfig.php(60):
>   Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getFirstSection()\n#6
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#7
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#8
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143):
>   Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#9
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#10
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#11
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Index/Interceptor.php(39):
>   Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, NULL)\n#12
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55):
>   Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#13
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#14
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#15
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#16
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#17
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#18
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#19
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#20
>   /home/efabrics/public_html/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#21
>   {main}","url":"/efabadmin/admin/system_config/index/key/3efe52c828dea94d7e8f3ff31c33a13c6fce6418791023ff92a34e48e36151dc/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Comment: Can you clear var/generation and try after clearing the cache.

Comment: There is no VAR/GENERATION folder. But there is a GENERATED directory in the magento root directory.

Comment: Was it working before? The magento2

Comment: Is there any custom module installed ?

Comment: this issue occur due to wrong xml in system.xml

Comment: Yes. Same version was working on this server, because there was some other issues, i deleted the old magento 2.2.2 and installed a new magento same version. I copied the htaccess, user.in and php.in from the old working server, so that i don't have any problem with the php settings.

Answer (score 0):

> Please check your system.xml of your custom module. There may tab, section, group and field have the same id or may have null on id attribute.